# How to open CHM file on specified node TOC (.NET)

Tags: .net, chm

Hi I need implement context help inside my .NET application.
I have .chm file and I'm looking for possibility to open it in standard viewer and hightlight required topic of TOC (or Index entry)

Any idea how to archive that ?

**EDIT:**

Maybe MS application used to open CHM file has some command line parameters which allows archive that?

BTW: Where can I find that app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to look into the [Help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.help.aspx) class. It's what I use to display help in Winforms applications.

Comment: Look's good - will check it. In the meantime - do you have any example (links) how to use it?

Comment: Sorry - Im not too lazy - I missed examples on a page you mentioned. Will check it first

Answer (score 6):

I think one of the following URL could work or point you to more "web hits" via google. But I think there are some restrictions sometimes like: maybe works only in IE, only if chm in trusted location, some url may only work on certain windows version, ....

```
mk:@MSITStore:C:\test.chm::/testpage.htm

ms-its:.\test.chm::/html/test.htm
```

---

Seems I wasn't specific enough. You should be able to use the above to launch hh.exe from within your application directly and passing this as URI as an argument.

Using System.Diagnostics.Process and launching hh.exe like this

```
hh.exe mk:@MSITStore:C:\test.chm::/test.htm
```

should do what you want.

Check [HTMLHelp commandline](http://www.help-info.de/en/Help_Info_HTMLHelp/hh_command.htm) for more examples

Comment: Can you please give me more info what I shall do wietk this synax?
Open it via iExplore, run as new process from c# ??

I just wanted to open Microsoft HTML Help application with specified help item highlighted and it's content displayed

Comment: I made my answer more specific

Comment: +1 because it really works. But I've found Jeff's post as best approach. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

Thanks Jeff I've found solution.

Below method doing that - maybe somebody finds it useful.
Thanks for help!

```
public static void ShowHelpByKeyword(Control sourceControl, string helpFile, string parameter) {
   Help.ShowHelp(sourceControl, helpFile, HelpNavigator.KeywordIndex, parameter);
}
```

Comment: i find it useful. thanks for an answer and for the theme ! :)