# How to create F1 help in windows forms using c#

Tags: .net, windows, chm

How do you create the keyboard shortcut(F1) in a windows form using c#. WinChm

Answer (score 21):

Add an event handler for a control's [HelpRequested](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.helprequested.aspx) event and then use the [Help.ShowHelp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.help.showhelp.aspx).

For example,

```
private void button1_HelpRequested(object sender, HelpEventArgs hlpevent)
{
   Help.ShowHelp(this, "helpfile.chm", HelpNavigator.TopicId, "1234");
}
```

You can use different [HelpNavigator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.helpnavigator.aspx) options to show things like the table of contents, etc.

See [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006312/how-to-open-chm-file-on-specified-node-toc-net) for more information.