# Determine topic id to open it in CHM file

Tags: c#, .net, chm

I am trying to implemented F1 help for my WinForm application. I have read this thread:

[How to create F1 help in windows forms using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029316/how-to-create-f1-help-in-windows-forms-using-c)

My question is how do I find the topic id of my topic in the CHM file? I am using HTML Help Workshop, and I have looked over every HTML file and option and could not find it. Thanks.

```
Help.ShowHelp(this, "helpfile.chm", HelpNavigator.TopicId, "1234");
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can define topic IDs for your help file as follows:

1. Open your help project (.hhp) in a text editor.
2. Add the `[ALIAS]` section and define IDs for the topics:

   ```
   [ALIAS]
   Foo=MyTopic.htm
   Bar=SomeFolder\AnotherTopic.htm
   ```
3. Add the `[MAP]` section and specify the ID values:

   ```
   [MAP]
   #define Foo 7
   #define Bar 42
   ```
4. Re-compile your help file.

More info here: [HTML Help - Context Help Ids](http://kb.helpwaregroup.com/ms-html-help/merge/contextids).

Comment: .NET still did not pick up on the alias, however I managed to hook the topic by hardcoding the .htm file.

Comment: @Serge: Sorry, my original answer was incorrect. Please see the updated answer.

Comment: Thanks Helen, good to know that, I was looking for this. There are some of us out there who still uses HHW :)