# connect a help file to application

Tags: c#

I want to connect a help file(.chm) to my windows application.
How do I can do this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this

```
string fbPath = Application.StartupPath;
string fname = "help.chm";
string filename = fbPath + @"\" + fname;
FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(filename);
if (fi.Exists)
{
Help.ShowHelp(this, filename, HelpNavigator.Find, "");
}
else
{
MessageBox.Show("Help file Is in Progress.. ",MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

}
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the [Help.ShowHelp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.help.showhelp.aspx) method for doing it on button presses etc:

```
private void button1_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
      string helpfile = "C:\MyHelp.chm";
      Help.ShowHelp(this, helpfile, mypage.htm);
}
```

and to link your help via the F1 key see this guide for a detailed explanation on how to do this:

http://www.dotnetspark.com/kb/162-open-help-file-on-f1-function-key-press.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Help.ShowHelp](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.help.showhelp(v=VS.90).aspx).

One example from the MSDN page:

```
private void Button1_Click(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {

        Help.ShowHelp(TextBox1, "file://c:\\charmap.chm");
    }
```

You can also check out these SO pages:

- [How to create F1 help in windowsforms using c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1029316/how-to-create-f1-help-in-windows-forms-using-c)
- [How to open CHM file on specified node TOC (.NET)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1006312/how-to-open-chm-file-on-specified-node-toc-net-)

Answer (score 1):

For Winforms, the excellent [Windows Forms Programming](http://www.sellsbrothers.com/writing/wfbook/) provides a very nice overview (chapter 3, implementing help). Some pointers:

- [HTML Workshop](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=00535334-c8a6-452f-9aa0-d597d16580cc&displaylang=en)
- The [Help](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.help.aspx) class
- The [HelpProvider](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.helpprovider.aspx) class
- The [HelpButtonClicked](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.helpbuttonclicked.aspx) event
- The [HelpRequested](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.helprequested.aspx) event